# C# Thread Queue Synchronize

Tags: c#, threadpool, queueuserworkitem

Greetings, I am trying to play some audio files without holding up the GUI. Below is a sample of the code:

```
if (audio)
{
    if (ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(CoordinateProc), fireResult))
    {

    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("false");
    }
}

if (audio)
{
    if (ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(FireProc), fireResult))
    {

    }
    else
    {
         MessageBox.Show("false");
    }
}

if (audio)
{
    if (ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(HitProc), fireResult))
    {

    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("false");
    }
}
```

The situation is the samples are not being played in order. some play before the other and I need to fix this so the samples are played one after another in order.

How do I implement this please?

Thank you.

EDIT: `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(FireAttackProc), fireResult);`

I have placed all my sound clips in FireAttackProc. What this does not do and I want is: wait until the thread stops running before starting a new thread so the samples dont overlap.

Comment: Threading is designed for executing tasks concurrently, playing one sound after the other is not concurrent execution. You've potentially got the right idea of playing sounds on a separate thread, but not _each_ sound. Petoj is correct.

Comment: Threading can also be used so the main GUI thread does not freeze while waiting for data. thats what i am trying to do here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just create one "WorkItem" and do everything there?

Comment: I am new at this. What is a WorkItem?

Comment: ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(HitProc), fireResult) there you add one "WorkItem"

Comment: ah you mean do the whole thing in one (Proc). well thats possible but i was just wondering if a group of threads can be ordered for execution or not.

Comment: they can but in your situation i don't se the reason for doing it... google c# Thread Synchronization...

Answer (score 1):

You can't guarrantee the order of execution of thread pool threads.  Rather than that, as suggested by others, use a single thread to run the procs in order.  Add the audio procs to a queue, run a single thread that pulls each proc off the queue in order and calls them.  Use an event wait handle to signal the thread each time a proc is added to the queue.

An example (this doesn't completely implement the Dispose pattern... but you get the idea):

```
public class ConcurrentAudio : IDisposable
{
    public ConcurrentAudio()
    {
        _queue = new ConcurrentQueue<WaitCallback>();
        _waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        _disposed = false;
        _thread = new Thread(RunAudioProcs);
        _thread.IsBackground = true;
        _thread.Name = "run-audio";
        _thread.Start(null); // pass whatever "state" you need
    }

    public void AddAudio(WaitCallback proc)
    {
        _queue.Enqueue(proc);
        _waitHandle.Set();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _disposed = true;
        _thread.Join(1000); // don't feel like waiting forever
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private void RunAudioProcs(object state)
    {
        while (!_disposed)
        {
            try
            {
                WaitCallback proc = null;

                if (_queue.TryDequeue(out proc))
                    proc(state);
                else
                    _waitHandle.WaitOne();
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                // Do something about the error...
                Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Error: {0}", x.Message), "error");
            }
        }
    }

    private ConcurrentQueue<WaitCallback> _queue;
    private EventWaitHandle _waitHandle;
    private bool _disposed;
    private Thread _thread;
}
```

Comment: yes i believe you understood my situation correctly. still im at loss regarding your code. i get the idea but not the implementation as i am  beginner at this. thanks and feel free to extend your post further if you like. i would very much welcome it.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) option !